# How to make a post request using the gogearbox framework

Tags: api, rest, go

I am currently stuck because I do not know how to complete my Post request for a project I am doing. I am using a framework called gearbox (I wanted to try something new). The main problem is I don't know how to bind the json to the new variable. So can anyone help me with this issue. For the info I can post the GitHub package. It's ***"github.com/gogearbox/gearbox"*** , Please help me.

I did try to look up the documentation,and I did try a few different functions but it didn't work so if anyone can help me please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide some code even if it doesn't work. It's usually a good starting point. This way we can avoid trying things you already tested out. I've briefly read the doc and didn't test the code below but you may try to look at the `ParseBody` function:

```golang
type Payload struct{
  FirstName  string `json:"firstname"`
  LastName  string `json:"lastname"`
}

requestHandler := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    var payload *Payload
    err := ctx.ParseBody(&payload)
    if err!= nil {
      ctx.Status(gearbox.StatusInternalServerError).SendString("Something went wrong when parsing your payload!")
    }
    // do something with your payload 
}
```

[reference here](https://github.com/gogearbox/gearbox/blob/a53b9b7ffff1ce9e65d91810fc69e3e4c3d8eec4/context.go#L135)

Comment: Thanks man! I did try the ParseBody method and it worked. From now on I will post the code. This is my first ever post so I'm inexperienced.

Comment: Happy you made it work. You can now tick the answer to mark it solved.

Comment: @CodingwithCyril